# не получается изменить значение в массиве

Tags: php

мне нужно перезаписать значение в "cityname" на значение которые в переменной $result, я попробовал вот так и у меня не получается

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/regions.json'), true);
foreach ($data as $datum) {

    $result = GeographicalNamesInflection::getCase($datum['cityname'], 'предложный');
    $cityfals = $datum['cityname'];
    $cityname = $result;

    $oldname = trim($cityfals);               

    $newname = trim($cityname);               

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {    

        if (in_array($oldname, $value)) {   

            $taskList[$key] = array('cityname' => "$newname");  
        }
    }

    file_put_contents('regions.json', json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)); 
}
```

массив выглядит таким образом

```
`"элиста": {
    "identyfyon": "8",
    "name_two": "Республика Калмыкия",
    "code": "8",
    "code_two": "8",
    "alias": "элиста",
    "region_name": "Республика Калмыкия",
    "popular": "no",
    "sort_top": "",
    "cityname": "Элисте",
    "regionname": "Республике Калмыкия"
  },`
```

на выходе я должен получить такой же массив только с заменённым значением cityname

Comment: Так вы пишите в `$taskList`, нет?

Comment: я попробовал так, с $taskList, другие значения массива теряются, и перезаписывается одно и тоже значение в cityname только в разные города

Answer (score 0):

обновить не получилось, но получилось так, заново создавать массив со значениями с прошлого массива

```
`foreach ($data as $datum) {
    $result = GeographicalNamesInflection::getCase($datum['cityname'], 'предложный');
    $cityfals = $datum['cityname'];
    $cityname = $result;

    $oldname = $cityfals;

    $newname = $cityname;

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

        if (in_array($oldname, $value)) {

            $taskList[$key] = array(
                            'identyfyon' => $datum['identyfyon'],
                            'name_two' => $datum['name_two'],
                            'code' => $datum['code'],
                            'code_two' => $datum['code_two'],
                            'alias' => $datum['alias'],
                            'region_name' => $datum['region_name'],
                            'popular' => $datum['popular'],
                            'sort_top' => $datum['sort_top'],
                            'cityname' => $newname,
                             'regionname' => $datum['region_name']);
        }
    }

    file_put_contents('cityname.json', json_encode($taskList, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
}`
```